# streaming videos with processing

Tags: java, video-streaming, processing

Processing has a Movie class (http://processing.org/reference/libraries/video/Movie.html) which is capable of playing videos. I have no problem with playing local video files with the following code.

```
public void setup() 
{
    size(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    myMovie = new Movie(this,/Users/mike/Documents/abc.mp4");

    myMovie.play();

}

public void draw() 
{
    //(WIDTH-myMovie.width)/2
    image(myMovie, 0, 0);
}


// Called every time a new frame is available to read
public void movieEvent(Movie m) 
{
    m.read();
}
```

But now i want to play streaming video from the internet, I don't know how to do it. I tried to just change the file name to a url link which ends with .mp4 (such as http://www.abc.com/abc.mp4), but it didn't work.

Anyone knows how to play streaming videos with processing?

Answer (score 0):

From the Processing reference on http://processing.org/reference/libraries/video/Movie.html

```
Datatype for storing and playing movies in Apple's QuickTime format.
Movies must be located in the sketch's data directory or an accessible
place on the network to load without an error.
```

If you want to play movies with a normal content type like mp4, ogg, etc, you're going to have to use a real video library, not the built in Movie object.

Comment: I want to play a normal content, but the file is on the internet, not a local one. But I failed to make it play the internet video. For local videos, it works.